# Anaconda Spyder RuntimeError (imp.py line 271)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, spyder

I get this error while running a sample code from Google Cloud API, but i assume this has nothing related to the API.

```
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 271, in
find_module

"not {}".format(type(path)))

RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not
<class'_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
```

Here is the Python code that i run

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
import six
import sys

def entity_sentiment_text(text):
    """Detects entity sentiment in the provided text."""
client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
    text = text.decode('utf-8')

document = types.Document(
    content=text.encode('utf-8'),
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

# Detect and send native Python encoding to receive correct word 
offsets.
encoding = enums.EncodingType.UTF32
if sys.maxunicode == 65535:
    encoding = enums.EncodingType.UTF16

result = client.analyze_entity_sentiment(document, encoding)

for entity in result.entities:
    print('Mentions: ')
    print(u'Name: "{}"'.format(entity.name))
    for mention in entity.mentions:
        print(u'  Begin Offset : {}'.format(mention.text.begin_offset))
        print(u'  Content : {}'.format(mention.text.content))
        print(u'  Magnitude : {}'.format(mention.sentiment.magnitude))
        print(u'  Sentiment : {}'.format(mention.sentiment.score))
        print(u'  Type : {}'.format(mention.type))
    print(u'Salience: {}'.format(entity.salience))
    print(u'Sentiment: {}\n'.format(entity.sentiment))
```

I did some research, some people suggest to add **init**.py, but i do have it in my directory. I wonder is there something wrong with spyder? While i run this file on Terminal using python to call the file, it works fine.

Here is the error points to:

```
def find_module(name, path=None):
    """**DEPRECATED**

    Search for a module.

    If path is omitted or None, search for a built-in, frozen or 
    special
    module and continue search in sys.path. The module name cannot
    contain '.'; to search for a submodule of a package, pass the
    submodule name and the package's __path__.

    """
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError("'name' must be a str, not 
        {}".format(type(name)))
    elif not isinstance(path, (type(None), list)):
        # Backwards-compatibility
 **ERR ==>**    raise RuntimeError("'path' must be None or a list, "
                           "not {}".format(type(path)))

    if path is None:
        if is_builtin(name):
            return None, None, ('', '', C_BUILTIN)
        elif is_frozen(name):
            return None, None, ('', '', PY_FROZEN)
        else:
            path = sys.path

    for entry in path:
        package_directory = os.path.join(entry, name)
        for suffix in ['.py', machinery.BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[0]]:
            package_file_name = '__init__' + suffix
            file_path = os.path.join(package_directory, 
         package_file_name)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                return None, package_directory, ('', '', PKG_DIRECTORY)
        for suffix, mode, type_ in get_suffixes():
            file_name = name + suffix
            file_path = os.path.join(entry, file_name)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                break
        else:
            continue
        break  # Break out of outer loop when breaking out of inner 
     loop.
    else:
        raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)

    encoding = None
    if 'b' not in mode:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            encoding = tokenize.detect_encoding(file.readline)[0]
    file = open(file_path, mode, encoding=encoding)
    return file, file_path, (suffix, mode, type_)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you update to our 3.2.6 version and try again? I think think this was already fixed.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba i still got the same problem after running conda update spyder, my spyder is currently at 3.2.6

Comment: The error is still point to the imp.py in anaconda python , at line 271 : RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>

Comment: Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) about this problem. It seems particular to `google.cloud`.

Comment: having the exact same problem